# ASP.NET Rich Text Box gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Im working on a web app here in C# and I have a listview. When I do an edit on the listview everything works great. In my notes field its a textbox, Id rather have it larger like a Richtextbox, but when I put that in there I get an error, other than label or textbox I cant seem to do anything. How can I make the notes field more like a rich text box area for a end user to edit?

Notes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NotesTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>' Width="700px" />
<br />
```

Comment: "when I put that in there I get an error" is extremely vague.  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Do you actually need a rich text box or are you just trying to get a multi-line textbox?

Answer (score 1):

`RichTextBox` is a WinForms control.  It does not work in the WebForms platform.  If you want a "rich text" editor, you'll have to find a third-party component that allows this type of editing.